# CodeIgniter form_checkbox and set_value in php foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have my form_checkbox and set_value inside a php foreach statement, this line is not working :

```
form_checkbox(array("name"=>"membershiptype[]","id"=>$membership['name'],
"value"=>$membership['id'], "checked"=>set_radio("membershiptype[]", $membership['id'], 
FALSE)))
```

I am trying to set up a validation when a checkbox is selected and something else is incorrect to return this value when it comes back to the page and displays an error for something else, right now it is not re-selecting them on validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my issue by removing the `[]` in my `set_value`

```
form_checkbox(array("name"=>"membershiptype[]","id"=>$membership['name'],
"value"=>$membership['id'], "checked"=>set_radio("membershiptype", $membership['id'], 
FALSE)))
```